# Combine certain elements of a list

Tags: python

I have this list of strings:

```
Mylist =  ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255', '/80', 'to', '255.255.255', '/88']
```

How can I get this as the final result:

```
Mylist = ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255/80', 'to', '255.255.255/88']
```

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to have a list of multiple tuples. It's just a list of strings.

Comment: `mylist[:3] + [mylist[3] + mylist[4], mylist[5], mylist[6] + mylist[7]]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python. Any idea on how to combine string[3] + [4] and string [6]+[7]? leaving other strings untouched?

Comment: @TonyTones One option is to create a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thank you to Evert

```
for line in Mylist:
     newline = line[:3] + [line[3] + line[4], line[5], line[6] + line[7]] 
     print (newline)

Mylist = ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255/80', 'to', '255.255.255/88']
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick `for` and `if` statement:

```
def merge_port(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for i,item in enumerate(input_list):
        if item.startswith('/'):
             output_list[-1] += item
        else:
            output_list.append(item)
    return output_list
```

This is just a quick work up, I have not tested, but should give you the idea.  You could also add error tests, if you encountered a list with the `/...` at the beginning of the list you would get an exception.

Comment: The danger here is that it alters the input list, while it confusingly also returns it. I generally expect a function that returns something, not to alter my input as well.

Comment: @Evert sure, I agree, not the best practice.  You can easily have it create a new object, see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to have some fun with your question and introduce the concept of regular expressions. Python handles this through the package `re` (hence the `import re`). This way we can match an item in that list to an IP address pattern and check if the item that follows it correspond to a port number with the format you've given.

Let me know if you have any questions:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

some_list = ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255', '/80', 'to', '255.255.255.255', '/88']
new_list = []

count = 0
ip_pattern = re.compile('^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$')
port_pattern = re.compile('/[0-9]*')

for i in some_list:
    count += 1
    if ip_pattern.match(i):
        try:
            next_item = some_list[count]

            if port_pattern.match(next_item):
                new_item = ''.join([i, next_item])
            else:
                new_item = i

            new_list.append(new_item)
        except IndexError:
            new_list.append(i)
    elif port_pattern.match(i):
        pass  # Don't add to the new list
    else:
        new_list.append(i)

print('Original List: {0}'.format(some_list))
print('New List: {0}'.format(new_list))
print('Formatted string: {0}'.format('\t'.join(new_list)))
```

Output:

```
Original List: ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255', '/80', 'to', '255.255.255.255', '/88']
New List: ['ASA', 'TD', 'UDP', '255.255.255.255/80', 'to', '255.255.255.255/88']
Formatted string: ASA   TD  UDP 255.255.255.255/80  to  255.255.255.255/88
```

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty easy, because python is simply awesome ^^

```python
output = input[:]  # Although I wouldn't call the input value input, because it shadows the builtin function
output[3:5] = [output[3] + output[4]]  # this makes the list shorter to fit the new list in
output[5:7] = [output[5] + output[6]]  # because the list is one shorter, the indices are one less each
```